# How to keep HostApduService as a background service on Android

Tags: java, android, deserialization, background-service, hce

I am currently developing an Android application that contains a HostApduService (HCE). My concern is: is it possible to keep this service in the background to allow pre-instantiated objects in the device memory?

My initial idea was to instantiate variables in the constructor of my service, however, it seems that this constructor is only called when the service is requested by an NFC reader.

This is a concern for me because I need to instantiate an object from a file via deserialization, which lengthens the NFC communication process of the service.

Therefore, it would rather arrange me to access a pre-instantiated object in memory of the device.

Here is how I implemented my service:

```java
public class HceService extends HostApduService {

    public HceService(){...}

    @Override
    public byte[] processCommandApdu(byte[] commandApdu, Bundle extras) {
      ...
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.[REDACTED">

    <application
            <service
            android:name="com.[REDACTED].services.HceService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NFC_SERVICE" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.action.HOST_APDU_SERVICE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.host_apdu_service"
                android:resource="@xml/apduservice"/>
        </service>
    </application>
```

Thank you in advance for your answers !

(Do not hesitate to ask for clarification if necessary!)